# How to preview database table changes SQL in DBeaver?

Tags: dbeaver

I am using DBeaver 21.2.0 and I have found the option to preview the SQL statements before saving modified data to the database (MySQL), through the Script icon in the bottom toolbar.

But when I modify the table structure (for example, add a column, remove a column...) no such option seems to exist. I can only save the changes to the database, but it is imperative for me to see the SQL statements before executing them.

Is that possible?

Comment: How do you modify the table structure? Usually, when you add/change/delete columns in the table tab via UI, DBeaver shows SQL Preview changes dialog with the ALTER/DROP Query after button "Save" clicking. You can check this behaviour in the Preferences. Preferences -> Editors. The "Show SQL preview dialog on editor save" must be enabled.